# Get entry by value from custom field

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, entrymodel

I have a field defined in my plugin called `video` with `AttributeType::Mixed` where I store a video_id and a title of a video. I need to look up the entry by the video_id (I can't do it via the the entry ID).

```
$entry = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$entry->section = 'video';
$entry->search('video: video_id=' . $videoID);
return $entry->first();
```

This works, but there has to be a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not SQL friendly at all to store multiple values (Title and Video ID) in a single column. The data is stored as a serialized string and all you can do is to use the pattern matching operator [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) to get the row you're after.

For best performance you should refactor your fields and store each of them individually. If all the data has to be in one field, store the field in its own table (like Matrix fields do).

If this is no option for you, I would recommend to not use the `search` parameter with your ElementCriteriaModel, but to prepare a [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) object using [buildElementsQuery](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#buildElementsQuery-detail) and add your "Video ID condition" using the `LIKE` operator I mentioned above, so you don't rely on up-to-date search indexes.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'video';

$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$params = array(
    ':video_id' => '%video_id='.$video_id.'%',
);
$query->andWhere('entries.video LIKE :video_id', $params);
$result = $query->queryRow();

return EntryModel::populateModel($result);
```